# how to implement auto zoom to a point using iPhone camera

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to implement auto zooming using iPhone camera. This is an additional functionality for barcode scanning. Barcode scanning is already implemented, but I've no idea about how to auto zoom to the barcode location. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: just bring the user user to hold his phone so that the barcode is in the center :P

Comment: this is some thing really urgent. Please if some one knows the hack for this, please pitch in.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the barcode sdk support only Iphone 3GS and iPhone 4  only..because these devices already having this autofocus feature (inbuild).u need not to care for autofocus ,if you are using iPhone 3GS or iPhone 4